# not able to understand scope of variable in this code

Tags: javascript, html

In this code `vid` is initialized inside the function, so how can it be used outside the function
( i.e how could `vid.play()` know that `vid` is initialised using `vid = document.querySelector("#myPlayer")`).

```
window.onload = init;

let vid;
function init() {
  console.log('page loaded, DOM is ready');
  vid = document.querySelector('#myPlayer');
  vid.ontimeupdate = displayTimeWhileVideoIsPlaying();
}

function playVideo() {
  vid.play();
}
```

Comment: Where did you call `init()` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have correctly identified that this is a question of "variable scope". I've added some comments to your code in the hope it clarifies things.

I suggest you look into: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-variables-scope-hoisting-in-javascript

```
// This variable is defined globally. It does not yet have a value, but it is available to everyone at this root level or deeper. All share a reference to the same variable.
let vid;

function init() {
    console.log("Page loaded, DOM is ready!"); 

    // This function must run FIRST so we assign the value found here
    // but we store it in a variable defined at the root/global scope
    // so we are changing a variable that is defined outside this function
    vid = document.querySelector("#myPlayer");

    vid.ontimeupdate = displayTimeWhileVideoIsPlaying;
}

function playVideo() {
    // This will throw an error if the above function does not run first
    // Until that runs vid is `undefined`.
    // But since the variable that is defined is at the global scope this
    // function is able to read the same value that the above function writes.
    vid.play();
}
```

Comment: shouldn't vid be passed as an argument to init function , for global vid to be initialized inside the function .

Comment: the link you provided didn't cover this type of declaration and initialization. @Chase,

Comment: Sure it does. It has an entire section called `Variable Scope` that covers exactly that. In terms of "if you should pass it as an argument". That's a question of preference. What you have written in your original question is perfectly legal and, if executed in the right order, will work fine. But I'd probably agree it isn't an "ideal" implementation.

Answer (score 1):

It can't, it will simply look at the `let vid;` variable. You have 2 possible scenario's here.

1. `init()` is called before `playVideo()`:

At the time `vid.play()` is called, your `vid` variable holds your video 
as `init` initialized it.

---

2. `playVideo()` is called before `init()`:

At the time `vid.play()` is called, your `vid` variable will be `undefined` and thus throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of `vid` like this

```
if (vid) {
 vid.play();
} else {
  alert('Video not initialized')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should distinguish between variable declarations and variable affectations (or initialization to use your words). Sometimes both actions are made at the same time (`let vid = 'value';`) but that's not mandatory.

In Javascript a variable can be used as long as it has been declared. Its value will then be `undefined`.

For the scope of your variable, it can be seen by both of your functions because it is declared ouside of it, look at the second snippet, if it would have been declared inside `init` function, it would only be accessible by it, and not visible outside of it.

```js
let vid;

function test(){
    console.log(vid); //declared and not initialized
}

function test2(){
    console.log(vid2); //not declared (and not initialized)
}

test(); //undefined value (no error)
test2(); //error: not declared
```

```js
function init(){
    let vid;
}
function test3(){
    init();
    console.log(vid); //declared in another scope
}

test3(); //error: not declared
```